# Return super function from alert handler

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

In my `shouldPerformSegue` I check if all player names are entered. If not I ask the user if they want to continue.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    // Check filled in players
    // var shouldPerform = true

    if (newPlayerCount < playerCount && newPlayerCount >= minPlayerCount) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Lege velden", message: "Je hebt een veld leeg gelaten. Weet je zeker dat je met \(newPlayerCount) spelers wilt spelen?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ja", style: .default, handler: { action in
            //shouldPerform = true
            return true
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nee", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
            self.markUnusedFields()
            //shouldPerform = false
            return false
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    //return shouldPerform
}
```

The `return`'s don't work since the handler isn't expecting it. How can I return the main function from the handler? I also can't make a variable which I set in the handlers (like in the comments) since that gets returned immediately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` is the right place to pop up an alert for confirmation. Instead, your controls should be connected to actions that pop up the confirmations, and *then* your actions can call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

Comment: with controls you mean the buttons on the alert?
So instead of `return true/false` I just call `performSegue` when I was returning true

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the function `shouldPerformSegue` presents the alert and then immediately returns. The alert actions are then executed after `shouldPerformSegue` has already finished.

I would try presenting the alert when the user presses the continue button instead of trying to evaluate if the segue should happen or not.

```
@IBAction func touchedContinueButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Check filled in players
    if (newPlayerCount < playerCount && newPlayerCount >= minPlayerCount) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Lege velden", message: "Je hebt een veld leeg gelaten. Weet je zeker dat je met \(newPlayerCount) spelers wilt spelen?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ja", style: .default, handler: { action in
            // The player chose to continue
            // Send them to the next view using the segue with identifier "mySegue"
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nee", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
            self.markUnusedFields()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

If you use this approach, don't forget to set the storyboard identifier of the segue to match the string in `performSegue(withIdentifier:)`

Comment: Instead of returning in the handlers I can do the performSegue like you mentioned. 
 (See other answer) That's working as well. Thanks anyway!